# Vue.js - watch particular properties of the object and load data on change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch

I have Vue component with prop named `product`, it is an object with a bunch of properties. And it changes often.

```
export default {
    props: {
        product: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {},
        },
    },
    watch: {
        'product.p1'() {
            this.loadData()
        },
        'product.p2'() {
            this.loadData()
        },
    },
    methods: {
        loadData() {
            doApiRequest(this.product.p1, this.product.p2)
        }
    },
}
```

The component should load new data when only properties `p1` and `p2` of  `product` are changed.
The one approach is to watch the whole product and load data when it is changed. But it produces unnecessary requests because `p1` and `p2` may not have changed.

Another idea is to watch `product.p1` and `product.p2`, and call the same function to load data in each watcher.
But it may happen that both `p1` and `p2` changed in the new version of the product, it would trigger 2 calls.

Will it be a good solution to use a debounced function for data load?

Or rather use single watcher for the whole `product` and compare new `p1` and `p2` stringified with their old stringified versions to determine if data loading should be triggered?

Comment: Hi, a small block of code would be great to make others understand, what you are trying to do.
I think that you need the product as a computed property
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Comment: I think that using debounce with watch for the whole product is a good solution. Debounce is good for performance. Having one watch for the whole product allows you to have all conditions for data loading in one place, it makes code easier to read and edit.

Comment: Or you can create a computed property that returns a string representation of p1 and p2, and watch this computed property instead.

Comment: how about going with the second method but saving a local variable of the timestamp of the last call, if the timestamp was less than a certain amount then don't load the data again, if it was longer than that then update the timestamp before reloading the data.

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches to this, each with pros and cons.

One simple approach I do is to use a watch function that accesses each of the properties you want to watch and then returns a new empty object. Vue knows `product.p1` and `product.p2` were accessed in the watch function, so it will re-execute it any time either of those properties change. Then, by returning a new empty object instance from the watch function, Vue will trigger the watch handler because the watch function returned a new value (and thus what is being watched "changed").

```js
created() {
  this.$watch(() => {
    // Touch the properties we want to watch
    this.product.p1;
    this.product.p2;

    // Return a new value so Vue calls the handler when
    // this function is re-executed
    return {};
  }, () => {
    // p1 or p2 changed
  })
}
```

Pros:

- You don't have to stringify anything.
- You don't have to debounce the watch handler function.

Cons:

- You can't track the previous values of `p1` and `p2`.
- Take care if `this.product` could ever be null/undefined.
- It will always trigger when `p1` or `p2` are changed; even if `p1` and `p2` are set back to their previous values before the next micro task (i.e. `$nextTick()`); but this is unlikely to be a problem in most cases.
- You need to use `this.$watch()`. If you want to use the `watch` option instead then you need to watch a computed property.

Some of these cons apply to other approaches anyway.

A more compact version would be:

```js
this.$watch(
  () => (this.product.p1, this.product.p2, {}),
  () => {
    // changed
  }
})
```

Comment: This would cause the watcher running if there's any change in the product, not neccessary changes in p1 and p2 properties because you return a new object every time

Comment: @KienHT Only if the `this.product` property was changed, not if any other property of `this.product` where changed.

Answer (score 2):

for you do ontouch event in vuejs while using it with your HTML inline
and you have an object model that house you other variable and you need to validate the any of the variable you will need to put them in watcher and use qoute ('') to tell vuejs that this is from a the model.email
hope this is useful

data() {
return {

```
        model: {},
        error_message: [],
    }
},
watch: {
    'model.EmailAddress'(value) {
        // binding this to the data value in the email input
        this.model.EmailAddress = value;
        this.validateEmail(value);
    },
},
methods: {
    validateEmail(value) {
        if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(value)) {
            this.error_message['EmailAddress'] = '';
        } else {
            this.error_message['EmailAddress'] = 'Invalid Email Address';
        }
    }
   


},
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing but it's much more helpful if you _explain_ your answers rather than simply dumping code.

Answer (score 1):

As some of other developers said you can use computed properties to monitor the changing of `product.p1` or `product.p2` or both of them and then calling `loadData()` method only once in each case. Here is the code of a **hypothetical** `product.vue` component:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        this is product compo
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "product",
    watch: {
        p1p2: function(newVal, oldVal) {
            this.loadData();
        }
    },
    props: {
        productProp: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {},
        },
    },

    computed: {
        p1p2: function() {
            return this.productProp.p1 + this.productProp.p2;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadData() {
            console.log("load data method");
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

I renamed the prop that it received to **productProp** and watched for a computed property called `p1p2` in that. I supposed that the values of data are in **String** format (but if they are not you could convert them). Actually **p1p2** is the concatenation of `productProp.p1` and `productProp.p2`. So changing one or both of them could fire the **loadData()** method. Here is the code of a parent component that passes data to `product.vue`:

```html
<template>
<section>
   
  <product :productProp = "dataObj"></product>
  <div class="d-flex justify-space-between mt-4">
    <v-btn @click="changeP1()">change p1</v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="changeP2()">change p2</v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="changeBoth()">change both</v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="changeOthers()">change others</v-btn>
  </div>
  
</section>
</template>

<script>
import product from "../components/product";

export default {
    name: 'parentCompo',

    data () {
      return {
        dataObj: {
          p1: "name1",
          p2: "name2",
          p3: "name3",
          p4: "name4"
        }
      }
    },
    components: {
      product
    },

    methods: {
      changeP1: function() {
        if (this.dataObj.p1 == "name1") {
          this.dataObj.p1 = "product1"
        } else {
          this.dataObj.p1 = "name1"
        }
      },

      changeP2: function() {
        if (this.dataObj.p2 == "name2") {
          this.dataObj.p2 = "product2"
        } else {
          this.dataObj.p2 = "name2"
        }
      },

      changeBoth: function() {
        if (this.dataObj.p2 == "name2") {
          this.dataObj.p2 = "product2"
        } else {
          this.dataObj.p2 = "name2"
        }

        if (this.dataObj.p1 == "name1") {
          this.dataObj.p1 = "product1"
        } else {
          this.dataObj.p1 = "name1"
        }
      },

      changeOthers: function() {
        if (this.dataObj.p3 == "name3") {
          this.dataObj.p3 = "product3"
        } else {
          this.dataObj.p3 = "name3"
        }
      }
    },
   
}
</script>
```

You can test the change buttons to see that by changing `dataObj.p1` or `dataObj.p2` or both of them the **loadData()** method **only** called once and by changing others it is not called.